# iPhone Delegates - How to use them correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 or 3 views in my iPhone application where I have various pieces of functionality that use delegates. In all cases the delegates are assigned to "self", responding specifically to that view's actions and interacting with instance variables.

However, if I do something that takes a bit of time with a delegate, and leave the view, obviously it crashes my app as the delegate methods get called on a view I've left.

Typically in my delegate methods I am doing things like interacting with IBOutlets, calling other instance methods, saving data to Core Data etc...

How can I work with delegates better? Is what I'm doing typical, or not?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the use case. If, for example, you've got a UINavigationController that manages a ViewController that use something such as Location Services, when you pop the View Controller off of the stack you're going to want to set the CLLocationManager's delegate to nil. You can do this in the dealloc method.

Comment: I guess its more around how I can use the same delegate for multiple views. I'm setting to self so that I can use specific code on each view, but that dies and crashes the app obviously if I leave the view too early.

Just wondering if I should always have a delegate set to self or should it be in another object instance out of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a specific example of an issue you're facing?

I've encountered this situation once when dealing with MapKit (race conditions involving delegate callbacks and delegate deallocation). However, in general, I think it's an indication of a bad design decision when your delegate becomes invalidated as a result of race conditions, but I could be wrong.

Typically, the objects that make use of your delegate should exist within the context of the delegate itself. So, for example, the same class that contains various `IBOutlet`s that you want to manage with delegate callbacks should also be the delegate of those `IBOutlet`s. That way, when the class (i.e., the delegate) is deallocated, the `IBOutlet`s are (hopefully) also deallocated, so they won't be making callbacks to anything.

bpapa's right. More generally, if you have a potentially lengthy delegate callback, either make sure that 1) the delegate is an object that won't be deallocated during the lifecycle of the delegator (e.g., `UINavigationController` managing `UIViewController`s) or 2) the delegator's `delegate` object is set to nil during the delegate's deallocation.

... That last sentence was a mouthful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your delegates should be declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

This ensures a weak reference so that when you dealloc the object which has `delegate`, it only removes the reference and NOT the corresponding object. using `(strong)` will cause a crash on dealloc.

When calling your delegate, you can check

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(MyDelegateProtocolCallbackMethodName:)] {
   [self.delegate MyDelegateProtocolCallbackMethodName:result];]
}
```

Generally I use delegates for proxy classes which fetch data from a server or edit screens like changing the title of a task in a todo list or editing a model in a database.

The advantage of a delegate is a very clear use case. If you find that multiple parts of your app need to be aware of when an event happens (triggered on 1 screen but perhaps listened for in another), I suggest using `NSNotificationCenter` to raise notifications, instead of or perhaps in addition to sending a message to your delegate.